# Finding which of the delimiters caused splitting at index value at strtok() in C

Tags: c, string

I found out exact locations of the splitting but now I am trying to figure out which of the delimiters caused splitting at which iteration ;

```
int main(){

char *string;
printf("Enter string:");
scanf("%s",string);
const char *delimiters = "12345";    
char *p = strtok( string, delimiters );

while ( p )
{
    printf("%d %s\n",p-string,p);        
    p = strtok( NULL, delimiters);
}
return 0;
}
```

This splits the string from necessary locations but I need to know which delimiter caused the splitting at each iteration since *delimiters is mixed up. Also result of my code generates a huge number at the end I couldn't understand why.

Comment: Read the documentation of `strtok()`, and you will find that the splitting delimiter will be overwritten by `'\0'`. It is lost, and if you don't have a copy of the original string, you can't retrieve it. You'll need to find another algorithm.

Comment: I recommend using strpbrk() instead, then you can read the character before changing it into the zero termination manually

Answer (score 0):

Use `strpbrk()` instead.

```
char s[] = "Hello World";

char *p = s;
char *tok = p;
p = strpbrk(p, "lW");

char sep = *p;
*p++ = '\0';

printf("sep: %c\n", sep);
printf("tok: %s\n", tok);

p = strpbrk(p, "lW");
// ...
```